# In Quickbooks Api retrieving a aggreate view of the transactionqueryrq

Tags: api, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using the QuickBooks Api to request transaction data from a QB database. However due to the number of transactions, it takes a long time for the request to come back. Is there a way of requesting a summarise view in the XML, i.e instead of getting data on TxnID level, I can get it to just aggregated the 'amount' by accounts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the request you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of requesting a summarise view in the XML, i.e instead of getting data on TxnID level, I can get it to just aggregated the 'amount' by accounts.

Using a `TransactionQueryRq`? No.

If you're trying to get summary data, you should look into the reporting features of the SDK/qbXML instead -- they are likely closer to what you need.